# Checking the validity of a basic expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function that accepts a string as a parameter and return a boolean value (True or False) that indicates whether that string represents a valid basic expression.

I have to assume that these valid expressions consist of one or more ***positive*** integers that are separated by basic operators (only +, -, *, and /). The string must start and end with integer. Moreover, a single space must always separate integers and operators in a valid expression.

For example:

```
>>> chandler("1") 
True
>>> chandler("-1") 
False 
>>> chandler("1 + 22") 
True 
>>> chandler(" 1 + 22") 
False # because this string starts with space 
>>> chandler("1 + ")
False 
>>> chandler("1 22 * 333")
False
>>> chandler("1  /  2")
False # because of two spaces instead of one
>>> chandler ("23 + 45 - 17 * 2")
True
```

I have no clues how and from where to start.
I am allowed to use only string and list related things (like methods)

Comment: This looks like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you're not allowed to use those, however, I'd advise making a [finite state machine](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finite-state-machines/) reading the string: first, look for a number, then look for a space, then for an operator, then a space, then a number, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use regular expressions to solve this problem:

```
import re

def chandler(s):
    regex = r'\d+( [+*/-] \d+)*'
    if re.fullmatch(regex, s):
        return True
    else
        return False
```

What we do here is make a regex string that specifies the pattern to recognize, and then call `fullmatch()` to make sure that the entire string `s` matches the given pattern. Let's go over each part of that:

```
r'             # the beginning of a regex string
\d             # this is shorthand for "any digit" - e.g. the characters 0 through 9
\d+            # adding '+' to it means "we want at least one of these"
[+*/-]         # this specifies a *group* of these four operators we're looking for
( [+*/-] \d+)  # We're looking for a single space, followed by any of those four characters, 
               # followed by another single space, followed by at least one digit
( [+*/-] \d+)* # Adding '*' means "we want at least 0 of that entire expression in the parentheses
```

We use `re.fullmatch()` instead of one of `re`'s other methods to make sure that the entire string matches what we want. If we used `re.match()`, then it would match anything with a number at the beginning, regardless of whether the rest of the string wasn't what we wanted.

`re.fullmatch()` returns a regex match object if the string matches, or `None` (which evaluates to false when you put it in an `if` statement) otherwise. We just test for whether it's `None` or not, and return `True` or `False` accordingly.

Comment: `# Adding '+' means "we want at least 0 of that entire expression in the parenthese"`

I think you meant adding `'*' `?

Comment: thanks a lot, green cloak guy!
I had no idea about re.
But your breakdown makes it so much easier to understand!
You are awesome!
I have one question.
if I write the group in this order [+-*/] then it shows error. But if I write exactly like yours then it works.
why the order is important here?

Comment: Certain regex characters have different meanings in different situations. For example, `+` and `*` have their "look for how many of this" meaning normally, but have no particular meaning when within a group. Similarly, the `-` character stands for "a range of characters" when you're putting it inside a square-bracket group (e.g. `0-9`). Putting it at the beginning or end is unambiguous that you don't mean it as a range; otherwise, you would need to escape it (write `\-` instead of `-`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
import re


def chandler(test_str):
    return bool(re.fullmatch(r'^\d+(\ [+-/*//]\ \d+)*$', test_str))

print(chandler("1"))
# returns True
print(chandler("-1"))
# returns False
print(chandler("1 + 22"))
# returns True
print(chandler(" 1 + 22"))
# returns False
print(chandler("1 +"))
# returns False
print(chandler("1 22 * 333"))
# returns False
print(chandler("1  /  2"))
# returns False
print(chandler("23 + 45 - 17 * 2"))
# returns True
```

Regex breakdown:

```
'\d+'
    '\d'' matches any digit (0-9)
    '+' means at least once,
    so '\d+' means one or more digits i.e. a number

'(\ [+-/*//]\ \d+)*':
    '\ ' This matches a space
        (The '\' is redundant can just have ' ')
    '[+-/*//]' will match one of these: +.-,* or /
        (we need to escape '*' and '/' with a '/' because they are special characters)
    '\ ' again matches a space
    '\d+' again matches a number
    This block will match thing like ' + 16',
        we can have any number of these so we add a '*'
        this is like the '+' but allows us not to have any matches.
    So this means zero or more copies of <space><operator><space><number>
```

Comment: I mistakenly put `\d*` instead of `\d+`. Fixed, thanks

Comment: Can you breakdown the regex please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How is everyone is overcomplicating it that much? Is just one line of code!

```py
import re

def chandler(s):
    return bool(re.match(r'^\d+(\ [\+\-\*\/]\ \d+)*$', s))
```

Simply, the regex maps the whole string from start `^` to the end `$` expecting one number `\d` (with at least one digit `+`).

It allows to add one the operation symbols (`[\+\-\*\/]`) if they are preceded by a space and followed by another space and again one number with at least one digit.

This last part can be repeated multiple times with operator `*`.

Comment: Shorter doesn't mean simpler, nor better.

Comment: It is both in this case ;)